# Date format is reseting on reloading kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have a issue using kendo grid. When i refresh the kendo grid with new data, column with date format is changed to default kendo format.

```
$("#refreshbtn").click(function(){

    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(createRandomDataOnRefresh(10));

});
```

Please look into this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardik043/Ahq6s/486/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/date-format-is-lost-when-manually-populating-datasource-in-jquery), this is an expected behaviour(I don't see why, though). So in your case you can fix your issue with two ways:

1. To parse the `Date` property to a kendo date object with [`kendo.parseDate()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-parseDate):

   You have to just proccess your result data and parse the `Date` properties:

   ```
   $("#refreshbtn").click(function() {
       var data = createRandomDataOnRefresh(10);

       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
       {
           data[i].Date = kendo.parseDate(data[i].Date);
       }

       $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);
   });
   ```

   [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/487/)
2. Use `dataSource.transport.read` as a function:

   ```
   transport: {
       read: function(options) {
           options.success(createRandomDataOnRefresh(10));
       }
   }
   ```

   So everytime you click the *Refresh* button(code below) it will read again as if it was reading from a remote source, and parse all your data again the correct way.

   ```
   $("#refreshbtn").click(function() {
       $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
   });
   ```

   [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahq6s/488/).

Now it is up to you. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var kendoGrid =$("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
kendoGrid.dataSource.data(createRandomDataOnRefresh(10));
kendoGrid.dataSource.read();
kendoGrid.refresh();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poojadhanani/Ahq6s/489/)

Comment: Did you checked your *Refresh*  button?

Comment: I don't think this is the behaviour expected by OP, but np, gl.